# add log to REST methods in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, logging

is there a smart and efficient way to add logs to all REST method approaches.
for now I’m using Nlog to a file log, but it's seems not so good to add log to each new method I’m adding to the WCF service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a [custom message inspector](http://cgeers.wordpress.com/2011/05/10/wcf-message-logging/). In this case you could write a [IDispatchMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx) for the server side.

Answer (score -1):

Could you not just hook onto the Application_BegingRequest and Application_EndRequest in the global.asax file?

This method works well for me, but it depends on what level of logging you wish to achieve.

Simple and effective.

Comment: I would recommend this solution as it ties it to ASP.NET. What if the WCF service is self hosted? Or hosted in a Windows Service.

Comment: If i'm honest the question is pretty vague. So either answer here will work. If it's hosted through ASP.net then this solution would better as it is easier. On the other hand, like all things, it depends :)